# not getting correct response for post method using alamofire,result is failure

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I am not getting correct response for post method using Alamofire.
Result is failure and in response content type getting text/xml instead of application/json, can anyone help me with this.

`

```
let params = ["mobile":"0000000000", "pin":"000000", "devicekey":"99", "deviceOs":"123456", "deviceOsVersion":"12", "userType":"employee"]
        var request = URLRequest(url: Login_URL! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue ("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params as Any, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        if let json = json {
            print(json)
        }
        request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

        Alamofire.request("Login_URL",method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
           .responseJSON(options: .allowFragments) { response in
                print("Request: \(response.request)")
                print("Response: \(response.response)")
                print("Data: \(response.data)")
                print("Result: \(response.result)")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)`
```

here parameters i gave was 0000000000 and 000000 for mobile and pin respectively
but i want to give dynamic values for this how i can do that.

Comment: Can you show what you code you tried and what kind of error you receiving ?

Comment: hi , i just got the output, it was url typo error

Comment: hi ,
Can you explain how we can take paramaters dynamically,
Ex: i have user name and password which should be dynamic, can u please explain how to do that using post method@Dhruv

Comment: @vineela you are asking about adding parameters to alamofire?

Comment: @vineela At least show your code, then it would be easy for us to suggest something on basis of your implementation.

Comment: @Dhruv i have posted the code, please check once and let me know... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be having values of `mobile` and `pin` in some variable.
Lets say, `strMobile` and `strPin` just replace it in your dictionary.

```
let params = ["mobile": strMobile, "pin":strPin, "devicekey":"99", "deviceOs":"123456", "deviceOsVersion":"12", "userType":"employee"]
```

Or else use `var` in place of `let` and then fill the key value .

```
var params = ["devicekey":"99", "deviceOs":"123456", "deviceOsVersion":"12", "userType":"employee"]
params["mobile"] = strMobile
params["pin"] = strPin
```

Comment: will try and let u know, ty

Comment: its working thank you :-)

Comment: Great. Seems like you're new. So I would suggest from next time to do some searching and then ask a question.

Comment: yeah i am new to this swift programming, i searched for post method, but didnt search for dynamic parameters

Comment: iam getting response in console, but can u tell how fetch it on simulator as iam not receiving any msg if i enter wrong number, iam getting response only in console saying that number is wrong, can u tell how to write func for that

Comment: What do you mean by in simulator ? You need UI to display on simulator. What I suggest you is go through basics or iOS and Swift. It won't work like this way...

Comment: yes, can u suggest any blog for that...

Comment: Try googling, theres no specific blog you can get one thing from also you can visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow